# How to use "clrsh" command

Tags: aix, remotecommand

I am trying to execute a command on remote shell, with the help of clrsh command form other user.

Problem:
clrsh running that command as a root on remote shell, but I want to be execute with the same user.

Comment: Where does this `clrsh` command come from?

Comment: clrsh is an AIX command

Comment: Just an AIX-command or does it belong to some package? (cf `lslpp -w $(which clrsh)` command). Does it have any advantage over `ssh`?

Comment: File                                        Fileset               Type
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /usr/sbin/clrsh                             bos.cluster.rte       File

Comment: Does it have any advantage over ssh?

Comment: this is password less communication

Comment: That can be achieved with ssh too.